# How do I get the option to create an iOS solution in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've installed Xamarin Studio and I can create Android solution just fine. I don't have the option to create iOS projects though.

[image: Xamarin Studio]

I've tried reinstalling multiple times but no change. Running Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I dug up a forum post that states that Xamarin Studio only supports iOS on Mac. I didn't see this anywhere in any of the tutorials or documentation so hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: this has changed: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio

Comment: As described in the linked article you can only develop/build iOS apps on Windows using Visual Studio. In my question I was trying to discover a way to do so using Xamarin Studio, which is a stand alone IDE for developing Xamarin apps (as well as other C# applications). As far as I can tell that is not possible and I believe the answers provided by @Whoami and myself stand correct.

Comment: Correct, you can only build iOS apps on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing Xamarin in Mac OS, and i could able to create successfully iOS project both in the simulator as well as in the iPhone Device.

Comment: As stated in my answer below, I discovered this from digging up a forum post on the subject. I'll give you the answer for the effort, though.